# Yahoo oauth2.0 redirect_uri from Java

Tags: java, tomcat, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

I have an issue with yahoo 2.0 oauth. After the user login there appears a problem. It says : "Developers: Please check the redirect URI in your request and submit again."

On my tests I used as redirect_uri the local tomcat (http://localhost:8080/...).

After lot of searches on google I couldn't found all the specification regarding the redirect_uri (and the yahoo documentation is not so good).

Maybe someone knows how can I bypass that issue (obviously I would like to test on my local tomcat first,not directly on real server).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Check configuration in your yahoo OAuth application.
`redirect_uri` - The URL in your app where users will be sent after authorization.

You need to have a `Servlet` (Service) with `redirect_uri` url pattern to process OAuth response.

I would suggest to try [Scribe library](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) for yout OAuth needs.

[Github API Example](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls)

Comment: I already use scribe but it supports only oauth 1.0 for yahoo.Anyway I have implemented the Yahoo2Api in order to support oauth 2.0,but I think that is not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify localhost as redirect_uri. Localhost is every machine so how yahoo can find it. You should specify real uri to server where You deploy your app. Also you can use

> implict authorization

.

Comment: Yes some API can send redirect to your machine but not all. Try to red documentation in Yahoo.